# Offsetting a range that is found manually

Tags: excel, vba

I have a situation where I am using these equations

```
=CELL("address",INDEX(J61:W61,MATCH(LARGE((J61:W61),1),J61:W61,0)))
```

To find the cell address of the largest value cell in that range.

For example, it gives me this as a result. $T$61 (which contains the highest value).
I now want to use that information and offset it upwards 51 rows to extract the title for this column. How can I use this information and a formula, or VBA to find the content of $T$10 in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Obtaining the cell address in this case is not necessary. What's more, `CELL` is a **volatile** function, and so should be avoided if possible.

Simply:

`=INDEX(J10:W10,MATCH(MAX(J61:W61),J61:W61,0))`

Regards

Comment: The reason that I am using this particular function is that I have 3 values that I need. I need to top 3 greatest value cell addresses. So I use the large function to adjust for 1st, 2nd, and 3rd highest values.

Comment: Then replace MAX with LARGE with the required parameter within the construction I posted. That doesn't change the point I made about obtaining the cell address being unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a way to use vba to do what I need

```
Sub Top_3_Problems()

First_Address = Range("D62")
Second_Address = Range("D63")
Third_Address = Range("D64")


First_problem = Range(First_Address).Offset(-51)
Second_problem = Range(Second_Address).Offset(-51)
Third_problem = Range(Third_Address).Offset(-51)

Range("B40") = First_problem
Range("B41") = Second_problem
Range("B42") = Third_problem




End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick example of how to do this in `VBA`

This is just a simple example. If implemented, objects need to be properly qualifed with a worksheet and the `Find` method needs to have options added

```
Option Explicit

Sub MaxHeader()

Dim Found As Range, SearchRange As Range

Set SearchRange = Range("J61:W61")
Set Found = SearchRange.Find(WorksheetFunction.Max(SearchRange))

If Not Found Is Nothing Then MsgBox Cells(10, Found.Column)

End Sub
```